# Proving geometrically that stereographic projection conserves circles

Tags: geometry, stereographic-projections

I am aware of a few analytical calculations showing that the stereographic projection sends circles on the sphere to circles on the equatorial plane. There are related questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1535983/80419).

What about a geometrical proof? I have found one somewhere that goes as follows.

Let $O$ be the center of the sphere and $S$ the pole doing the projection. Choose a circle $C$ on the sphere lying on a plane $P$, and denote its center $A$. The rays joining $S$ to the circle $C$ cross the equatorial plane $P'$ at some points, which we want to prove form another circle. Let $M$ and $N$ be the two points on the circle $C$ such that they belong to the $SOA$ plane. Their stereographic projection on the equatorial plane are denoted by $M'$ and $N'$.

[image]

The angles noted in the attached figure can easily be proven equal, leading to the two angles $SMN$ and $SN'M'$ being equal. This means that the planes $P$ and $P'$ are symmetrical to each other by reflection across the axis $SA$ (shown as an arrow). Now, the proof follows saying that the "cone" from $S$ to $C$ has the same symmetry, so that its intersections with the two planes $P$ and $P'$ are "equivalent". As a consequence, the two intersections are circles, and this proves the theorem.

But wait. To me, this is not really a "cone". But fine, it does not need to be. However, it does not seem symmetrical across $SA$: taking the symmetric point of $N$ or $M$ will clearly not land on the same "cone". So that would mean that the two shapes made by intersecting with $P$ and $P'$ should not be equivalent; consequently, stereographic projection would not send circles to circles.

Where is my error?

Comment: there is a proof by picture in Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen, Geometry and the Imagination. I will see if I can find the correct pictures on line.  Alright, mostly pages 248-251

Comment: can't have everything; they do not show page 250, but do 248, 249, 251  https://books.google.com/books?id=7WY5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=hilbert+cohn-vossen+stereographic+projection+and+circle-preserving&source=bl&ots=EblPIVuYmY&sig=ItVCyPwLkK7EPwL_-Q-tIWSg6B0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZtNCs3JrRAhUN6WMKHfYpDvQQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=hilbert%20cohn-vossen%20stereographic%20projection%20and%20circle-preserving&f=false

Comment: Are you aware that, by sterographic projection, the image of the center is not the center of the image ? Said otherwise, the centers of the circle on the sphere and the center of the corresponding circle on the equatorial plane are (generally) not aligned with $S$.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I did not know, but what does it change for this question?

Comment: It was just a remark, without direct incidence on the question.

Comment: An answer to your problem may be found here:
https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/Stereographic.pdf
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cone is perhaps an *oblique* one, but it is a cone we are looking at: based on the circle $C$ from plane $P$, with summit $S$. 
(Note however, that being oblique only means, from other perspective, that it's a straight cone based on another conic section.)

Now the main point is that - as seen in current picture - the plane $P'$ meets this cone *in the same angle* as $P$ does. So the conic section of $P'$ will be *similar* to that of $P$, so will be a circle.

The wording is not too lucky: I guess the symmetry is about the cone itself.

Comment: I can accept that this definition of a cone, but I still don't see that symmetry in this case. The angles might be the same for the two planes, but they are on opposite sides of the cone, so that a symmetry is required. You say that it is a straight cone: what does this mean? Does it imply its symmetry across an axis?

Comment: @fffred: The sphere is symmetric "front to back" (i.e., in the plane of your diagram), so the cone has elliptical cross-sections in planes orthogonal to its axis $SA$, and one axis of these ellipses is perpendicular to the plane of the diagram. The relevant symmetry is, as you say, reflection in $SA$ (i.e., reflection in the plane perpendicular to the plane of the diagram and containing $SA$); the cone is preserved because its cross sections are ellipses, and the reflection plane bisects each along an axis.

Comment: I like this argument, and I am trying to clarify it to myself. Perhaps like this: we are dealing with a cone, and it has an obvious plane of symmetry passing through the vertex. It will necessarily have another plane of symmetry passing through the vertex. Now we reflect the circle section in that plane and get another circle section.