# How can we say that $\tan90^\circ=+\infty?$

Tags: trigonometry

Usually we take, $$\tan90^\circ=+\infty$$

But how fair is it? From the tan curve we get $\tan90^\circ$ is inditerminate. Can someone explain please?

Comment: We don't say that. In a loose sense, the tangent of the right angle is "infinite", but no sign is implied.

Comment: I don’t say that ... I say it’s undefined ! In a limit procession sense that would make sense

Comment: See [Extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Comment: There was a post to this not long ago that should answer your question...[Find the possible values of $\tan x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665410/finding-the-possible-values-of-y-tanx/2665446#2665446)

Comment: FYI: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424005/what-does-infinity-in-complex-analysis-even-mean/2424111

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tangent of $90^{\circ}$ is undefined. $\tan 90^{\circ}=\infty$ is a shorthand way of saying that as $\theta$ gets very close to $90^{\circ},\ \tan \theta$ becomes arbitrarily large; it isn't meant to be taken literally.  You'll see a more detailed discussion of this phenomenon when you take calculus.

Comment: +1 ... though I'm not sure a typical calculus course would include a discussion of that particular abuse of notation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Right.  By "this" I meant "as θ gets very close to 90∘, tanθ becomes arbitrarily large," but I see that I wasn't very clear.  I'll see if I can come up with a better way to say it.

Comment: This also bothers me because it goes to $-\infty$ from the other side.

Comment: @Randall Good point.  I didn't even notice the + sign in the OP's post.

Answer (score 2):

The [query](https://www.google.be/search?biw=1527&bih=834&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=hZpIW9aXAsGZsAfoiYPgDw&q=tangent%20special%20values&oq=tangent%20special%20values&gs_l=img.3...0.0.0.103850.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.img..0.0.0....0.BWoDu13Y9U8) "tangent special values" on Google images shows numerous tables of values. Most of them say "not defined", "undefined" or "-" for $\tan 90°$. I saw one with $\pm\infty$, one with "Infinity", and another with $\infty$.

I bet that $+\infty$ is even more scarce and IMO would be a true mistake. So this "usually" is excessive.

By default, Wolfram Alpha considers complex numbers and reports $\tilde\infty$, the complex infinity.

Interestingly, Microsoft Mathematics returns "Indeterminate" in the real mode, and $\tilde\infty$ in the complex one, while the Calculator just says "Invalid input".

Answer (score 2):

If you've ever seen this, it was abbreviating a left-hand limit; the right-hand limit is if course $-\infty$. Depending on the context, one might only care about a one-sided limit.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, $\tan 90°=+\infty$ is wrong because the positive sign is enforced, whereas this only makes sense for the left-side limit.

$\tan 90°=\pm\infty$ and, more loosely $\tan 90°=\infty$ are more acceptable as they leave room for the indeterminate sign.

In any case, we admit that $\tan90°$ is short for $\lim_{\theta\to90°}\tan\theta$.