# Limits in two different paths

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Consider the following limit
$\lim_{z\to i}\frac{1}{z-i}$. Let $y=z-i$ so when $z\to i$ $y\to0$. Now
$$\lim_{z\to i}\frac{1}{z-i}= \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{y}=\infty$$. Is there another way to show the limit does not exist?

Also, I got stuck in the following limit $$\lim_{z\to 1} \frac{\overline{z}-1}{z-1}$$

I know the general ideas. take two paths that get through the point $(1,1)$ but I could not come with these two paths

Comment: The take two paths approach is for when you want to show a limit doesn't exist. But that second function is continuous at the point you want to take the limit.

Comment: Also that first limit is not $\infty$, since it could be positive, negative, or multiplied by some kind of $i$ depending on the direction you're coming from. But what you can say is that since thr limit from one direction doesn't exist the whole thing doesn't either.

Comment: @NinadMunshi it is $\infty$. There is a pole? What is your definition of $\infty$?

Comment: @psl2z the limit $$\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{1}{y}$$ is $\infty$, but per my last comment it could be negative or some other complex phase.

Comment: @NinadMunshi usually in the complex case one says the limit is $\infty$ if the absolute values goes to $\infty$, i.e. if it converges in the Riemann sphere to $\infty$?

Comment: @psl2Z I know wolframalpha uses a complex infinity, but that sounds like a personal preference and not a standard terminology, especially not in the context of being precise about limits. One point compactifications don't exactly preserve metrics or limit sets.

Comment: @NinadMunshi See for example this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2424016

Comment: @NinadMunshi I edited the question there was a typo

Comment: Take $t \mapsto 1 + it$ and $t \mapsto 1+ t$.